# Is stdin disrupting loop over items?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a file **names.txt** which contains names of data-files like 'data0.dat, data1.dat ... data10.dat'. I would now like to loop bash commands over these files. I usually use

```
while read fnm; do
    analysis1 $fnm
    analysis2 $fnm
done < names.txt
```

But this does not work for me now. I suspect that its because some commands take stdin, and/or that some are piped to /dev/null:

```
while read fnm; do
    echo 0 5 | analysis1 $fnm
    analysis2 $fnm > /dev/null 2>&1
done < names.txt
```

I find that if I instead use the construction

```
for next fnm in `cat names.txt`; do
    echo 0 5 | analysis1 $fnm
    analysis2 $fnm > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Everything works fine. Can someone explain this or tell me where/how stdin gets misused in the first version?

Answer (score 3):

Stop analysis1 and analysis2 reading from stdin:

```
while read fnm; do
  analysis1 $fnm </dev/null
  analysis2 $fnm </dev/null
done < names.txt
```

Comment: Alternatively, use a different file handle for the `read` instead of standard input: `while read fnm <&3; do ...; done 3< names.txt`.